# What is a self-contained, rhetoric phrase? (Brevity is soul of wit)

Tags: meaning, phrases, expressions

This [related question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/45607/is-there-a-term-for-a-self-fulfilling-sentence) touched on redundancy which appeared as a strict upgrade from an autological "[word](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autological_word)" to a "phrase" to me.

It would be enlightening to find more instances that provokes a string of thoughts such as one of Shakespeare's from *Hamlet*:

> "[Brevity is the soul of wit.](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/74850.html)"

Also, how would you place them in taxonomy or nomenclature? Is this a scholar's pun?

Comment: Pearls of wisdoms, words of wisdom? Experience is simply the name we give our mistakes.
Oscar Wilde

Comment: Omne ignotum pro magnifico

Comment: I believe this is in danger of being closed as being "listy", though I wouldn't be in favour of that.
Also, @Crosscounter, the preface to The Picture of Dorian Gray and Hamlet's soliloquy are full of phrases of a similar kind.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of terms come to mind:

Epigram, if it's more a turn of phrase.

Koan, if it's more to inspire or enlighten.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Your answer could be improved by linking to dictionary definitions and perhaps some more explanation; I understand a *koan*, for example, to be a philosophical paradox rather than an aphorism, and an *epigram* to be a type of short poem. I encourage you to take the [site tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and to read through the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for further guidance.